# Html Tag Handler not called in Android N for "ul", "li"

Tags: android, spannablestring, android-7.0-nougat

We have a custom `TagHandler` in our app for bulleted list etc.

```
html = "<ul><li>First item</li><li>Second item</li></ul>";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, new ListHTMLTagHandler(density));
} else {
  //noinspection deprecation
  result = Html.fromHtml(html, null, new ListHTMLTagHandler(density));
}
```

The `handleTag()` function in my `TagHandler` is called for `ul`, `li` in API-23 and below but not called in API-24 (Android N).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry. Edited.

Comment: _"...but not called in API-24..."_ Did you run it on an Android N device?

Comment: There's a bug on the Android bug tracker for this. Please star it for attention.
http://b.android.com/214637

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Yes. Emulator and Nexus 5X with Android-N

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is evident from the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) of `Html.java` that, `TagHandler.handleTag()` is called only if the framework doesn't process it, itself.

Currently, the framework doesn't seem to process it well.
[image: Android N li tag handling]

But even if it did it well, you would want to customize it anyway. The best way to deal with this is to replace the default `ul`, `li` tags with your own tags. Since the framework won't process your custom tags, your `TagHandler` will be asked to handle it.

```
static final String UL = "custom-ul";
static final String OL = "custom-ol";
static final String DD = "custom-dd";
static final String LI = "custom-li";

public static String customizeListTags(@Nullable String html) {
  if (html == null) {
    return null;
  }
  html = html.replace("<ul", "<" + UL);
  html = html.replace("</ul>", "</" + UL + ">");
  html = html.replace("<ol", "<" + OL);
  html = html.replace("</ol>", "</" + OL + ">");
  html = html.replace("<dd", "<" + DD);
  html = html.replace("</dd>", "</" + DD + ">");
  html = html.replace("<li", "<" + LI);
  html = html.replace("</li>", "</" + LI + ">");
  return html;
}
```

And then you can process your html string like

```
html = customizeListTags(html);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, new CustomTagHandler());
} else {
  //noinspection deprecation
  result = Html.fromHtml(html, null, new CustomTagHandler());
}
```

Comment: This is not without it's problems as well. For example if your input string is your replaced tag version of something like this <ol>...</ol><ul>...</ul> the tag handler will get them in this order: open ol, open ul, close ul, close ol.

Comment: @bran.strat Why would the order change?

Comment: can you please add your `CustomTagHandler` class code

Comment: @AkashRaghav You need to implement [Html.TagHandler Interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) . If you are looking for an example, [I found one here](https://gist.github.com/mlakkadshaw/5983704)

Comment: @VivekBarai it can be any string that is not a standard tag in HTML. "CustomUL" for example. It can't be "ul", "ol", or "b" etc. which are standard tags in HTML.

Comment: Tags should be replaced with custom ones. They cannot be replaced with capital equivalents as they ignore casing with `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score -1):

I've published a compatibility library to standardize and backport the Html class across Android versions which includes more callbacks for elements and styling:

> https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat

Specifically, given this invocation:

```
Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, source, 0,
        imageGetter, tagHandler, spanCallback);
```

you will be interested in implementing TagHandler for unknown tags, and SpanCallback for customizing the Spans that HtmlCompat creates from HTML.